# How to create dynamic grid in WPF ? i mean create rows and columns based on Generic list

Tags: wpf, data-binding, uniformgrid

```
            [![Grid Example][1]][1]Image refers to data that will be populated dynamically from database.will change based on button clicked from side menu.
            All blue data will be in list of containing object inside it will list of all  items 


              [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OV10Q.png


            This is my model :

             public class RestaurantMenu
                {
                    public int MenuId { get; set; }
                    public string MenuName { get; set; }
                    public IList<RestaurantSubMenu> SubMenus { get; set; }
                }

                public class RestaurantSubMenu
                {
                    public int SubMenuId { get; set; }
                    public string SubMenuName { get; set; }
                    public int MenuId { get; set; }
                    public bool HasToppings { get; set; }
                    public bool HasSizes { get; set; }
                    public bool HasModels{ get; set; }
                    public IList<RestaurantProduct> Products { get; set; }
                }

                public class RestaurantProduct
                {
                    public long ProductId { get; set; }
                    public string ProductName { get; set; }
                    public string ProductDescription { get; set; }
                    public long MenuId { get; set; }
                    public long SubMenuId { get; set; }
                    public int IsNonVeg { get; set; }
                    public double ProductPrice { get; set; }
                    public string ProductPhoto { get; set; }
                    public int MaximumToppingCount { get; set; }
                    public IList<RestaurantProductSize> ProductSizes { get; set; }
                }
```

how can i bind that to uniform panel?i wanted to bind  ProductName  from RestaurantProduct through records and bind and then show like buttons.
how can i bind that to uniform panel?i wanted to bind  ProductName  from RestaurantProduct through records and bind and then show like buttons.  how can i bind that to uniform panel?i wanted to bind  ProductName  from RestaurantProduct through records and bind and then show like buttons.  how can i bind that to uniform panel?i wanted to bind  ProductName  from RestaurantProduct through records and bind and then show like buttons.

**WPF XAML Code this is used to bing product names but its not working.Need help on how can we add this to our view just like shared image**
**WPF XAML Code this is used to bing product names but its not working.Need help on how can we add this to our view just like shared image**
**WPF XAML Code this is used to bing product names but its not working.Need help on how can we add this to our view just like shared image**
**WPF XAML Code this is used to bing product names but its not working.Need help on how can we add this to our view just like shared image**
**WPF XAML Code this is used to bing product names but its not working.Need help on how can we add this to our view just like shared image**
**WPF XAML Code this is used to bing product names but its not working.Need help on how can we add this to our view just like shared image**
**WPF XAML Code this is used to bing product names but its not working.Need help on how can we add this to our view just like shared image**

```
    <ItemsControl Grid.Column="1"  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=RestaurantMenu}" >
                          <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                             <DataTemplate>
                                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SubMenuName}">
                                   <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                      <DataTemplate>
                                         <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Products}">
                                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                               <UniformGrid Columns="5" />
                                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                               <DataTemplate>
                                                  <Button Content="{Binding  Path= ProductName}"/>
                                               </DataTemplate>
                                            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                         </ItemsControl>
                                      </DataTemplate>
                                   </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                </ItemsControl>
                             </DataTemplate>
                          </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                       </ItemsControl>
```

Comment: I would use a [`UniformGrid`](https://wpf.2000things.com/tag/uniformgrid/) to get this kind of layout.  If each color is a catagory, so that you essentially have a list of lists, you could easily do this with a `ItemsControl` containing the `UniformGrid` as the `ItemTemplate`

Comment: How can i iterate to this list to bind to model  
private List<Product> products;

public class Product {
    public string name;
    public List<Price> prices;
}

public class Price {
    public double price;
    public string name;
}

Comment: Can you add that class data to the question so it can be properly formatted please?

Comment: Brandley Thanks for your help.Can you please help me out to  ProductName  .My List Object is  RestaurantMenu -- >  RestaurantSubMenu --> RestaurantProduct (ProductName)

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do something like this using an `ItemsControl` inside another `ItemsControl`, using a `UniformGrid` for layout:

[image]

XAML:

```
<Window
    x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    Title="MainWindow"
    Width="800"
    Height="450"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainWindowVm />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <ScrollViewer>
        <ItemsControl Margin="8" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Catagories}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Products}">
                        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <UniformGrid Columns="5" />
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock
                                    Margin="1"
                                    Padding="1"
                                    FontSize="24"
                                    FontWeight="Bold"
                                    Foreground="White"
                                    Text="{Binding Path=Name}"
                                    TextAlignment="Center"
                                    TextWrapping="Wrap">
                                    <TextBlock.Background>
                                        <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}, Path=DataContext.Color}" />
                                    </TextBlock.Background>
                                </TextBlock>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Window>
```

View-Models:

```
class MainWindowVm
{
    public MainWindowVm()
    {
        Catagories = new ObservableCollection<Catagory>(new[]
                                                            {
            new Catagory(new[]
                             {
                                 new Product() { Name = "Chinese" },
                                 new Product() { Name = "Free Choice" },
                                 new Product() { Name = "BBQ-Original" },
                                 new Product() { Name = "Beefy One" },
                                 new Product() { Name = "GoGo Special" },
                                 new Product() { Name = "Ham & Mushroom" },
                                 new Product() { Name = "Hawaiian" },
                                 new Product() { Name = "Meaty-One" },
                                 new Product() { Name = "Pepperoni-Plus" },
                                 new Product() { Name = "GoGo Special" },
                                 new Product() { Name = "Alligator" },
                                 new Product() { Name = "Half & Haf" },
                                 new Product() { Name = "New Yorker" },
                                 new Product() { Name = "classic" },
                                 new Product() { Name = "Garlic Sizzeler" },
                                 new Product() { Name = "Double Pepperoni" },
                                 new Product() { Name = "Chicken Delux" },
                             },
                         Colors.Blue),
            new Catagory(new[]
                             {
                                 new Product() { Name = "Chicken Hot" },
                                 new Product() { Name = "Mexicana" },
                                 new Product() { Name = "American Hot" },
                                 new Product() { Name = "Flaming Touch" },
                                 new Product() { Name = "Maxican Passion" },
                                 new Product() { Name = "BBQ Beast" },
                             },
                         Colors.Red),
            new Catagory(new[]
                             {
                                 new Product() { Name = "Vegitarian Hot" },
                                 new Product() { Name = "Vegitarian" },
                                 new Product() { Name = "Cheese & Tomato" },
                             },
                         Colors.Green),
            new Catagory(new[]
                             {
                                 new Product() { Name = "7\" Pizza 2 Toppings" },
                                 new Product() { Name = "Lunchpox pizza" },
                             },
                         Colors.Orange),
            });
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Catagory> Catagories { get; }
}

class Catagory
{
    public Catagory(IEnumerable<Product> products, Color color)
    {
        Products = new ObservableCollection<Product>(products);
        Color = color;
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Product> Products { get; }
    public Color Color { get; }
}

class Product
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

You will want to make your real view models implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` of course.

Comment: Thanks Brandley!! Worked for me